# Why do baseband transmissions use TDM?

Tags: networking

To the best of my knowledge, baseband transmissions use (only) time division multiplexing. Why is that so?

TDM isn't as efficient as statistical multiplexing. Why is TDM preferred for baseband transmissions?

Comment: "_To the best of my knowledge, baseband transmissions use (only) time division multiplexing._" That simply is not true. Many different ethernet standards, from the very first to the most recent, use baseband (10Base-5, 10Base-2, 10Base-T, 100Base-TX, 1000Base-T, 10GBase-T, 25GBase-T, 40GBase-T, etc.), and ethernet does not use TDM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transmission band and the multiplexing scheme are almost entirely independent.

E.g. practically all Ethernet PHY variants use baseband signaling but they used CSMA/CD for access multiplexing (while that was still in use). Nowadays, there's only frame-level, dynamic multiplexing which doesn't fit any classic paradigm (and even lives in the data link layer, above the physical layer were the data is modulated and transmitted).